# Azure Data Factory - Data Flow - Join- Broadcast

Tags: azure-data-factory

On 30th April 2020, Azure Data Factory Data Flows show a new option on the Optimize Tab of the Join Activity in the Data Flow. I get a validation error on the pipeline that atleast one side should be a part of the Broadcast. When I fixed the validation issues and published the data factory all of the data flows have broken. Please find attached the snapshot. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrXn2.png)

Comment: Non-equality comparison logic requires a minimum of 1 stream to be fully broadcast. Please ensure that your Integration Runtime is sized appropriately.

Comment: Adding error on Data Preview - DF-DSL-001 - DSL stream has parsing errors
Line 27 Position 35: no viable alternative at input 'department_uid undefined'
Line 27 Position 61: mismatched input ',' expecting '(' - RunId: ec43a261-2a66-4d4f-9d7b-af736d6b8c3c

Comment: Old code in script Source, Target join(department_uid == t_department_uid,\n\tjoinType:'left',\n\tbroadcast: 'none')~> LeftJoin

Comment: New code in script Source, Target join(department_uid undefined t_department_uid,\n\tjoinType:'left',\n\tbroadcast: 'both')~> LeftJoin

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clear your browser cache and reload your pipeline?  There are some updated libraries that seem to have put your browser into an incomplete state.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved next day 5/1/2020. We tried using Edge as well as Chrome with same results, so thinking not cache. Next day everything was working again.